# ngCloak directive is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used the ngCloak directive like this

```
<div ng-repeat="note in ctrl.notes1">
        <span class="ng-cloak">{{note.$$hashKey}}</span>
        <span class="label" ng-bind="note.label"></span>
        <span class="author" ng-bind="note.done"></span>
</div>
```

When I refresh the page it's showing uncompiled raw data like {{note.$hashkey}}. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following CSS rules to the head section of your html file to ensure the rules are available immediately on load.

`[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}`

Otherwise they will be activated when you load the angular.js file, which is usually too late to prevent the display of raw templates.

Answer (score 0):

The css rules that make ng-cloak work are embedded by angular.js file. So if it is included at the end of html file it might not work as expected.

You can fix it by moving the following script tag to the head section of your html:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

Or you can add the following css rules to your css file included in the head section of html:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```